# Gradle : Could not find method jacocoTestCoverageVerification() in Jenkins

Tags: gradle

My gradle version is 3.5 in jenkins. But still i am getting error Could not find method jacocoTestCoverageVerification()  in Jenkins.

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
  violationRules{
    rule{
        limit{
            counter = 'LINE'
            minimum = 0.7
        }
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoCoverageVerification
```

to the top of your `build.gradle` and you're done.